# Register a route for two different viewsets that inheruse the same model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django REST framework and I've a configuration like this one:

```
router.register(r'foo', FooViewSet)
router.register(r'foo-mini', MinFooViewSet)
```

`FooViewSet` and `MinFooViewSet` are pretty identical ("min" hones inherit from the former), use same `queryset` but simply change the `serializer_class`.

The serializer class used by `MinFooViewSet` returns less fields from the same model.

I've a weird behavior (probably standard but I don't understand it): seems that I can have only one route for every model. In facts the generated API index is like the following:

```
"foo": "http://localhost:8001/api/v1/foo-mini",
"foo-mini": "http://localhost:8001/api/v1/foo-mini",
```

So both endpoints point to the same URL, that use the last (`MinFooViewSet`) configuration.

What I'm missing?

Comment: I would suggest to keep only one viewset and create multiple serializers and select serializers conditionally.

Comment: @CrazyGeek seems good: can you point me to example/documentation of this approach?

Comment: Here is an example http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_serializer_classself

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks. Although I'm still curious about the werid behavior I had before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirements, It seems like you need to make your api generic but it should have different behaviour based on some condition such as mini, which should return some other data as per `FooMiniSerializer` so below mentioned mechanism provides you facility to select any serializer class based on some condition.

[get_serializer_class(self)](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_serializer_classself)

Returns the class that should be used for the serializer. Defaults to returning the serializer_class attribute.

May be overridden to provide dynamic behavior, such as using different serializers for read and write operations, or providing different serializers to different types of users.

For example:

```
def get_serializer_class(self):
    if self.request.user.is_staff:
        return FullAccountSerializer
    return BasicAccountSerializer
```

I would suggest you to keep only one api url along with one viewset and then you can conditionally select any serializer using `get_serializer_class` method.

Hope this would be helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

Use base_name='something'

```
router.register(r'foo', FooViewSet,base_name='foo')
router.register(r'foo-mini', MinFooViewSet,base_name='foo_mini')
```